# Got some serious issue on django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am getting error while saving data  in database.Error shows something like this

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

views:

```
class BusinessDetails(APIView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = DetailSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        BusinessDetails(
            serializer.save()
        )
        return Response({"message": "sucess", "code": status.HTTP_201_CREATED, "details": serializer.data})
    return Response({'message': 'failed', 'error': serializer.errors})
```

urls.py

```
path('detail/', BusinessDetails.as_view()),
```

Comment: This is very strange: `BusinessDetails(serializer.save())` - what was your intention there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you need to pass the view name to save the data??

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = DetailSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
    return Response({"message": "sucess", "code": status.HTTP_201_CREATED, "details": serializer.data})
    return Response({'message': 'failed', 'error': serializer.errors})
```

Comment: i think he conflicted the View name with model name that might be the issue

Comment: still for saving the data he doesnt need Model name too. just serializer.save() is enough if its a ModelSerializer

Comment: didnt know that.. i was using ModelSerializer as serializer till now... thanks

Answer (score 0):

view name and the model name is same. just rename one and you are good to go.